# How to view a blob without downloading it from Azure

Tags: android, azure, blob

I'm trying to access a blob file from Azure. In the "Get started" on their website it gives a description on how to download it to a local directory. What I want to know is, is there a way to view the blob file without having to download it. Use facebook for example. We can see images on a newsfeed but dont have to save them directly to the device.

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your container's Access level to "Public Blob" it will allow public read access to your blobs in your container.  Then you can just use the URL associated with the blobs and treat the images like any other web based resource.